# How to re-order 'columns listing in list module in Typo3'

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I'm setting up a storage folder where records can be entered via tca, I need to display two columns in the backend when they are listing, two columns are displaying now but the issue is one column is far from another column, needed to display columns both near. I used description_column in ctrl section (TCA) to display the second column. Where do I need to change to re-order the columns?

attaching the screenshot below: volume column is needed near name column, now it is far away

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for the configuration `label_alt` and `lable_alt_force`. with this you can change the shown label of a record to a concatenation of multiple fields:

this needs to be configured in the `ctrl` part of the TCA of the records.

```
'ctrl' => [
    'label' => 'header',
    'label_alt' => 'header,subheader',
    'label_alt_force' => 1
],
```

be aware: this will change the label in all usages, not only the list display

see the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/8.7/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html?highlight=label_alt#label-alt)